# JavaFX ComboBox: исчезает выбранный элемент в выпадающем списке

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Исчезает (визуально) выбранный элемент из выпадающего списка `ComboBox`.
Сам выпадающий список - `ObservableArrayList(ArrayList<Label>)`.
Элементы выпадающего списка отображает `Label` при помощи  `setCellFactory`.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ComboBox<Label> comboBox = (ComboBox<Label>) scene.lookup(CHOICEBOX + i);
    switch (i) {
        case 0: comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Choices0)); break;
        case 1: comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Choices1)); break;
        case 2: comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Choices2)); break;
        case 3: comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Choices3)); break;
    }

    comboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Label>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Label lbl, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(lbl,empty);
            setGraphic(lbl);
        }
    });

    choiceBoxes.add(comboBox);
}
```

В данном случае `choiceBoxes` всего лишь `ArrayList<ComboBox<Label>>` и `Choices` это `ArrayList<Label>` соответственно.
Нужно, чтоб элементы выпадающего списка не пропадали визуально.

Изначально, после выбора элемента из списка выбранный элемент менял цвет текста `Label` на белый (понятия не имею почему).
Это я решил, сменив цвет текста на черный в установленный `Font` в `Label`.
Я попытался так же сделать с элементами выпадающего списка, но результата не дало.

Comment: В операторе `switch` отсутствуют `break` в отдельных `case`-ах, соответственно для всех комбобоксов всегда будет вызываться "последний" case и устанавливаться список значений `Choices3`: `comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Choices3));`

Comment: Забыл про него совсем, но это не изменит ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Поразмышляв , я пришел к такому решению:

Помещаем нужные `Label`  В `VBox` (а `VBox` в значение `setVisible(false)`) ,а дальше вешаем слушатель через `EventHandler` на `ComboBox` по нажатию лкм.  После нажатия Лкм по `ComboBox`  значение `setVisible(true)` . Дальше , на эти `Label` вешаем слушатель по нажатию которых `СomboBox` ставил значение полученное от `Label`.

Да, это костыль, зато рабочий. Предлагайте более лучшие решения.